# how to run makefile in ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu, makefile

There are two simple .c files add.c and hello.c. this is my makefile-

```
all:  add.exe hello.exe

add.exe: add.o

    gcc -o add.exe add.o



hello.exe: hello.o

    gcc -o hello.exe hello.o



add.o: add.c 

    gcc -c add.c



hello.o: hello.c 

    gcc -c hello.c
```

on typing `make` on terminal it shows all those four commands, but when i try to run this using `./all` it says

```
bash: ./all: No such file or directory.
```

`./hello.exe` or `./add.exe` works fine.

when I type ./all on my friend's pc, it shows proper output.

[image]

Comment: I've just noticed that you've tagged this as `ubuntu` but you're compiling `.exe` programs?  My answer still stands but which OS are you using and which OS is your friend using?

Comment: Both of us are using ubuntu as virtual machine. Actually it is windows operating system.

Comment: Actually, the extension is not so important within linux. It's just a name.

Answer (score 7):

Your friend's PC is doing something strange and its not clear from your question what they've done.  Your PC is acting normally.

Calling `make all` Will compile everything, but it doesn't actually make a program called `all`.  It only compiles two programs: `hello.exe` and `add.exe`.

So calling `./all` should fail because that is asking to run a program called `all` which doesn't exist.

It's quite possible that your friend has written themselves a program or script called "all".  You'll need to ask your friend what that script / program does and how it does it.

**Edit**

To see what your friend has done open a terminal on your friends pc (like the one in your screen shot) and type the command

```
ls -lh
```

This will list all the files in that directory.  Look for one named "all".  It might look something like this (with the word "all" in green):

```
-rwxr-----  1 appy appy 67 Oct 23 15:05 all
```

Assuming that's there you can look at the contents of it by typing

```
cat ./all
```

To get yours to work like your friends, create a similar file with the same contents.  To make it runnable you may need to change the file permissions:

```
chmod u+x all
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. What you are saying is i cannot get output for both files together? i have to run them separately? I have added an image. We both have done same thing. Still outputs are different. ./all works for her and not for me.

Comment: Yeah. That's right.  Something has been done differently on your friends machine.  I notice that you're working in your home directory, not creating a folder for the exercise.  It may be that something your friend has done previously has left that `all` program there.  So even if you have both done the same thing for this exercise its possible your friend has done another exercise before that's now interfering.

Answer (score 0):

"all" in this case is what is called a "pseudo-target" in `make` terminology. Since there is no build command under the `all: ...` line, there is nothing that will actually create a file called `all` (and in fact, having a file in that directory named `all` and having a timestamp newer than the `.c`, `.o` and `.exe` files is likely to confuse `make`). The pseudo-target here is simply a way to say that both the other `.exe` files must be built for `make` to consider its job done.

Assuming this is GNU Make, an entry `.PHONY: all` will tell it that `all` does not really correspond to a file that should exist.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have to run both files separately or what? I'm not getting. I've edited my question and added the screenshot of terminal from my friend's pc. ./all executes both program.